# What does #AT mean in d&d?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, helping

Farmer; AC 7; Level 0; hp 6; #AT 1; D 2-8;
XP 16

i am a new player and cannot understand what these mean. Can someone explain to me?
I am trying to play The Temple of Elemental evil

Comment: This question would be improved by a little editing, especially specifying the edition of D&D you're playing, and specifying where the stat line you're asking about came from.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding that you're trying to play the Temple of Elemental Evil (“ToEE”) doesn't help us figure out what edition of D&D you're playing, because there are multiple editions of ToEE as well. In fact, it's even more important to know now, because it's entirely possible that the problem isn't reading “#AT”, it might be that you're trying to understand a copy of ToEE for a different D&D than you're playing. So we do need to know what edition of D&D you're playing. Worst case, check the publishing year of the Player's Handbook that you use, because that will tell us which edition.

Comment: don't answer in comments